# Adding reference to Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger gives me red squiggly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have created a .NET Core Web API, and I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger) to add swagger support.

I have added the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` nuget package, but when I add `using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;`, there's a red squiggly under `Swashbuckle`. I'm unable to call `AddSwaggerGen`

Does anyone have a working sample, or know where I went wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of vs are you using 2015 or 2017

Comment: I had this issue with 2017 when installing nugget I just close VS and re open and everything works.

Comment: It was actually a case of restarting VS -.-

Comment: VS 2017 is the buggiest version jet. I thought it was only me for this but I guess it happens to more people might be good to rise a ticket on VS issues page. I guess that what happens with agile a bunch of untested "features" that they wait to see who will complain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed that part of the tutorial using vs2017 and everything seems ok to me:
https://github.com/RSereno/TodoApi2

You could check `*.csproj` file to see if the reference was added correctly:

`<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>`

The  red squiggly thing helps you find out whats happennig (Is it not found? Ambiguous, etc.)

Ps: I can't comment so I tried it to put it has a response.